# CakePHP 3 : Unknown method

Tags: cakephp, model, cakephp-3.0

I am creating a function in model to find all related services.

function in `ServiceCategory.php`

```
class ServiceCategory extends Entity
{

    public function relatedServices($id)
    {
        return $this->find('all', [
          'conditions' => [
            'where' => [
              'id !=' => $id
            ],
            'limit' => 5
          ]
        ]);
    }
}
```

And calling in `ServiceCategoriesController.php`

```
public function view($id = null)
    {
        $serviceCategory = $this->ServiceCategories->get($id, [
            'contain' => ['Services']
        ]);

        $relatedServices = $this->ServiceCategories->relatedServices($id);

        $this->set('serviceCategory', $serviceCategory);
        $this->set('relatedServices', $relatedServices);
        $this->set('_serialize', ['serviceCategory']);
    }
```

But it gives `Unknown method 'relatedServices'`

Is there any thing wrong I am doing ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The code is in the wrong class

In the question:

> class ServiceCategory extends Entity

This is an [entity](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html) class

> $relatedServices = $this->ServiceCategories->relatedServices($id);

This is making a call on a [table](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html) object, table objects and entities do not inherit from each other, the method is unavailable to the table class.

### Move the code to the table class

The direct solution is to move the code to the table class:

```
// src/Model/Table/ServiceCategoriesTable.php
namespace App\Model\Table;

class ServiceCategoriesTable extends Table
{

    public function relatedServices($id)
    {
        return $this->find('all', [
          'conditions' => [
            'where' => [
              'id !=' => $id
            ],
            'limit' => 5
          ]
        ]);
    }
```

Though the arguably correct/better way to do that is to implement a finder:

```
// src/Model/Table/ServiceCategoriesTable.php
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Query;
use \InvalidArgumentException;

class ServiceCategoriesTable extends Table
{

    public function findRelatedServices(Query $query, array $options)
    {
        if (!isset($options['id'])) {
            $message = sprintf('No id in options: %s', json_encode($options));
            throw new InvalidArgumentException($message);
        }
        
        $query->where(['id !=' => $options['id']);

        return $query;
    }
```

Which would be called in exactly the same way as other [find calls](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#using-finders-to-load-data):

```
$relatedServices = $this->ServiceCategories->find(
    'relatedServices', 
    ['id' => $id]
);
```